# Difference between "no" and "no other"

Tags: grammar

Can anyone who knows the language well please tell me the difference between **"no"** and "**no other"** in the following sentences? Are they both correct? In speaking, I have seen both are used.

- **No** student in the class is as strong as Alice is.
- **No other** student in the class is as strong as Alice is.

Answer (score 5):

They are both correct, but there is a slight difference that could be made.

When using "**No student**" doesn't necessarily imply that Alice is a part of the class , while "**No other student**" implies that Alice is a part of the class, because of the word other.

Be mindful of that difference, but in the end it isn't a big deal if you prefer to say one over the other.

Comment: It might help to point out there's nothing particularly unusual about *No student in the class is as clever as the teacher*, but *No **other** student in the class is as clever as the teacher* would only make sense if the preceding context had identified one or more students who ***are*** that clever.

Answer (score 1):

Some native speakers will use this form to indicate that Alice is the strongest student in the class, that she has no peer in strength:

> No other student in the class is as strong as Alice is.

But **other** is unnecessary there. Moreover, it can also be a cause of slight confusion, as that pattern could be used to describe situations where there were two (or more) students tied for strongest, Jane and Alice:

> Jane is as strong as Alice. No other student in the class is as strong as Alice is.

where **other** is in relation to *Jane*, not Alice.